# How to remove unwanted numbers from Int column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with the columns

- Process Varchar(30)
- Last_End_Time Integer format '99:99:99'

By mistake the data got loaded for some of the columns in the following format

```
Process Last_End_Time  
ABC 17:04:30  
BCD 2.05:30:20  
CDE 3.04:20:50  
DEF 15:20:52
```

The unwanted numbers need to be removed only while selecting the data and not from the table. My output after selecting data from the table should be

```
Process Last_End_Time  
ABC 17:04:30  
BCD 05:30:20  
CDE 04:20:50  
DEF 15:20:52
```

I am using Teradata Version 14. Please help.

Comment: Well, you can't load values like `3.04:20:50` into an `INTEGER` column, please double check the definition. If it's actually an integer you can simply use `Last_End_Time MOD 1000000`.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. Actually I do not know how it happened but as you said those values cannot be loaded. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, I was again getting wrong data. For 7.22:00:10 it was 900,010 and for 6.16:00:00 it was 600,000. Is there any possibility to get the output as 22:00:10 and 16:00:00

Comment: What is actually stored? Can you do a `cast(Last_End_Time as number)` and a `trim(Last_End_Time)` and show the result? What's the correct datatype: `TYPE(Last_End_Time)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The datatype of TYPE(Last_End_Time) is Integer and when I did cast(Last_End_Time as number) and a trim(Last_End_Time) the result was 1900010 for 7.22:00:10 and 181945 for 18:19:45

Comment: Did you use SQL Assistant? Seems like it's using the format, but not as expected, 190 / 24 = 7 days 22 hours. `Last_End_Time MOD 240000` seems to fix it, but you better find out what's the actual meaning of `1900010` and how it's loaded.

Comment: Awesome!!! You are just brilliant. Well as of now we are just selecting data from the table but I will later look into it and find out why it got loaded in this way. Thanks a lot. You saved my day!!!